# Python selection sort debug

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a selection sort function. There is a bug appears and I dont know how to
fix it.Here is my code:

```
def selection_sort(numbers):
  outlist=[]
  for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    minIndex=i
    for j in range(i+1,len(numbers)):
        if numbers[j]<numbers[minIndex]:
            minIndex=j
    numbers[minIndex],numbers[i]=numbers[i],numbers[minIndex]
    numbers = [str(i) for i in numbers]
    #print(numbers)
    outlist.append(numbers)
    #print(outlist)
  return outlist
```

I am expected to get a output list. In this list there are many lists that show how the function apply changes on the input.
But after I put each step ('numbers') in 'outlist'. I cannot get what I want: the outlist is not in right order.

Here is the test case that I have used:

**Input:**

```
43 42 18 14 3 45 24 14 50 26
```

**Output:**

```
3 14 18 42 43 45 24 14 50 26

3 14 14 42 43 45 24 18 50 26

3 14 14 18 43 45 24 42 50 26

3 14 14 18 24 45 43 42 50 26

3 14 14 18 24 26 43 42 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 45 50

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 45 50
```

But it suppose to be like:

```
3 42 18 14 43 45 24 14 50 26

3 14 18 42 43 45 24 14 50 26

3 14 14 42 43 45 24 18 50 26

3 14 14 18 43 45 24 42 50 26

3 14 14 18 24 45 43 42 50 26

3 14 14 18 24 26 43 42 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 50 45

3 14 14 18 24 26 42 43 45 50
```

Also, after I added 'print(numbers)', it shows that before I put 'numbers' into 'outlist' every step is correct:

```
['3', '42', '18', '14', '43', '45', '24', '14', '50', '26']

['3', '14', '18', '42', '43', '45', '24', '14', '50', '26']

['3', '14', '14', '42', '43', '45', '24', '18', '50', '26']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '43', '45', '24', '42', '50', '26']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '24', '45', '43', '42', '50', '26']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '24', '26', '43', '42', '50', '45']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '24', '26', '42', '43', '50', '45']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '24', '26', '42', '43', '50', '45']

['3', '14', '14', '18', '24', '26', '42', '43', '45', '50']
```

Comment: Maybe try `outlist += numbers` instead of `outlist.append(numbers)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

be aware of the deepcopy

```
import copy
def selection_sort(numbers):
  outlist=[]
  for i in range(len(numbers)-1):
    minIndex=i
    min_value = numbers[minIndex]
    for j in range(i+1,len(numbers)):
        if numbers[j]<numbers[minIndex]:
            minIndex=j
    numbers[minIndex],numbers[i]=numbers[i],numbers[minIndex]
    outlist.append(copy.deepcopy(numbers))
 #    print(outlist)
  return outlist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = [ 6, 9, 2,5,4,3,1,7]
    print selection_sort(num)
```